# PFFacebookUtil Pod

Tags: objective-c, facebook, parse-platform

I currently have a problem using [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook] since PFFacebookUtils.h has moved into another Framework, ParseFacebookUtils. When I add **pod 'ParseFacebookUtils'** in my Podfile and then do **pod install** I get this error:

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements: 
- Facebook-iOS-SDK required by Podfile 
- Facebook-iOS-SDK (= 4.1.0) required by Podfile.lock 
- Facebook-iOS-SDK (~> 3.9.0) required by ParseFacebookUtils (1.2.21)
```

My Podfile looked like this:

```
platform :ios, ‘8.4’

pod ‘Parse’

pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'

pod 'ParseFacebookUtils'
```

Can anyone tell me if pod 'ParseFacebookUtils' is the correct pod to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ParseFacebookUtilsV4` pod, this includes all of the following pods:

- `Parse`
- `FBSDKCoreKit`
- `FBSDKLoginKit`

For my case, I also must use pod `FBSDShareKit` or I get errors thrown my way for this missing framework. By using `ParseFacebookUtilsV4` you will have access to the `PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook()` function and all others within `PFFacebookUtils`.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

ParseFacebookUtils should be fine, but try using FacebookSDKCoreKit instead. Facebook-iOS-SDK is deprecated.

https://cocoapods.org/pods/FBSDKCoreKit

And like it says on the site, you may want 'FBSDKLoginKit', and 'FBSDKShareKit' pods also.

Comment: So my Podfile should look something like this?: platform :ios, ‘8.4’

pod ‘Parse’

pod ‘FBSDKCoreKit’

pod ‘FBSDKLoginKit’

pod ‘FBSDKShareKit’

Comment: Ok finally I got it to work! Thanks you so much. I was able to install those pods. Now the only problem is I am still now able to do [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook] since PFFacebookUtils.h has moved into another Framework, ParseFacebookUtils. Are you aware if there is a pod to install ParseFacebookUtils?

Comment: Arite never mind. I got it to work! Thank god! This took too long... haha